# GET http://example.com/get-data.php?url=... 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send a "get" request to my own php file called get-data.php using an ajax call. If I run it on my local xampp server, it works perfectly fine, but on a public server I recieve a 403 error.

my ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get-data.php",
    data:{
        url: url
    },                  
    success: function (data) {
        data= JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        $('.main-content').html(`<a href="${data.link}"><button id="download" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Download</button></a>`);


    }
});
```

my get-data.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
  $url = $_GET['url'];
 echo  file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: `data:{'url': url}, ` and how you are getting `url`? and what value it has? also jquery library is added or not?

Comment: Check whether you have right privileges ?

Comment: my url is "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsJLLEwUYZM" and yes i do have the jquery library included. also I encoded the url before actually sending the request

Comment: And check that your server allows `file_get_contents()` on url's by seeing if `allow_url_fopen` is On in `phpinfo()` if they allow you to run that

Comment: check Apache's log files